# Differences between "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis" and "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis.Redis"?

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, azure-redis-cache

I am a little bit lost. I am reading Microsoft documentation for ASP.NET Core caching using Redis.
And the documentation suggests to use Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis which is an open source third party library.

But I've seen some other tutorials are using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis, which is a more native asp.net core.

And at the end they both use the same interface IDistributedCache.

Why do I need Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis?
What advantages it has over Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

A look at the dependency graph for [Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis) and [Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis) reveals it.

`Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis` is based on StackExchange redis 1.x library, whereas `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis` is based on 2.x of the same library.

Also `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis` doesn't seem to target the 3.1 extension libraries (`Microsoft.Extensions.Options`/`Caching.Abstractions`) where the other does.

So for .NET Core 3.x and newer use `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis` as the previous one may not be maintained as long as the new one.

Comment: It's SOO confusing, there is no mention in the official documentation about the recommendation of a package not developed by Microsoft
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I just switched from Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis to Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis with Azure Redis, and I am seeing response rates improving dramatically. 50ms redis lookups were common, now 2ms is common. Crazy.