# Which version of Redis client should I use (Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis or Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis)

Tags: .net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

It seems there are 2 different Redis clients that Microsoft provides:

- Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis
- Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis

I see that both are widely used, but cannot figure the difference.

It seems that the first one is not supported anymore and all development has switched to the other one, but cannot find any confirmation.

Comment: In https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.1 they recommend the 2nd. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59847571/differences-between-microsoft-extensions-cashing-redis-and-microsoft-extensions as well

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that, just wondering what the other one is then? Have not seen the other question, thanks. Seems it was a duplicate actually